# Beta arbitrage in CAPM

Tags: beta, capm

i'm following the "[Computational Investing 1](https://class.coursera.org/compinvesting1-002)" course at Coursera.org, I was affascinated by the Beta arbitrage of CAPM

Video: https://class.coursera.org/compinvesting1-002/lecture/view?lecture_id=119

It shows, that if I found Betas and weights, I could make profit in Bearish and bullish markets. 
Strategy: SHORT for the Higher Beta, and LONG for Lower beta.

Is that really works? What are the bad scenarios? What he didn't say?

[image]

Do you know some code in R or Python, that calculate Betas? Someone has already applied this theory?

Answer (score 4):

This is in essence the idea behind Andrea Frazzini's paper '[Betting Against Beta](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~lpederse/papers/BettingAgainstBeta.pdf)'. There are various ETFs that aim to exploit the premium.

In R, you can do just do a linear regression using the `lm(Y~X)` which includes an intercept or using `lm(Y~X+0)` which regresses without an intercept. Assuming you've saved the model in variable `lm.r`, then to get the coefficients, you simply `coef(lm.r)`.

In package `PerformanceAnalytics`, there are built in functions whereby you can just plug in the parameters, independent and dependent and risk free rate to give out the coefficients.

For python, you should take a look in the `pandas` package for regression analysis. Last time I checked its inside the package but was being moved to `stats-model` package for reasons beyond me.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use excel using "single index model"

Comment: That's a solution for Excel and if I Google it it seems you have to do a fair bit of work, down-voted.